# ¿Cómo puedo meter un archivo pdf en una base de datos MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Cómo puedo meter un archivo pdf en una base de datos MySql?
 Tengo el código que me permite meter imágenes pero un pdf no consigo hacerlo.

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]))
{
  # verificamos el formato de la imagen
  if ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/gif" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/bmp" || $_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/png")
  {
    # Cogemos la anchura y altura de la imagen
    $info=getimagesize($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]);
    //echo "<BR>".$info[0]; //anchura
    //echo "<BR>".$info[1]; //altura
    //echo "<BR>".$info[2]; //1-GIF, 2-JPG, 3-PNG
    //echo "<BR>".$info[3]; //cadena de texto para el tag <img

    # Escapa caracteres especiales
    $imagenEscapes=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, file_get_contents($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]));

    # Agregamos la imagen a la base de datos
    $sql="INSERT INTO `imagephp` (anchura,altura,tipo,imagen) VALUES (".$info[0].",".$info[1].",'".$_FILES["userfile"]["type"]."','".$imagenEscapes."')";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);

    # Cogemos el identificador con que se ha guardado
    $id=mysqli_insert_id($link);

    # Mostramos la imagen agregada
    echo "<div class='mensaje'>Imagen agregada con el id ".$id."</div>";
  }else{
    if($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="application/pdf" ){


        echo "El archivo seleccionado es un pdf.";
        // Aquí debería ir INSERT INTO `imagephp`pero no sé cómo. 

    }else{

        echo "<div class='error'>Error: El formato de archivo tiene que ser JPG, GIF, BMP o PNG.</div>";

    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Te valdría guardar el archivo en el sistema de ficheros local y guardar en base de datos la ruta a ese fichero?

Answer (score 1):

Usa el tipo `BLOB` (longblob) para el campo en la base de datos, de esa manera:

```
CREATE TABLE resources (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    filename VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    mimetype VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    content LONGBLOB NOT NULL
);
```

Suponiendo que guardaremos un fichero subido por formulario:

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], 'r');
$fileContent = fread($fp, filesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
$fileContent = addslashes($fileContent);
$sql = "INSERT INTO resources (filename, mimetype, content) VALUES( $fileName, $fileType, $fileContent)";
```

No obstante, te aconsejo guardar tus ficheros en el sistema de archivos local, las razones más comunes para hacerlo son:

- Velocidad (Rendimiento) de la aplicación.
- Facilidad de acceso.
- Copias de seguridad de la base de datos más rápidas y de menor tamaño las bases de datos ocupan menos espacio.

PD: El rendimiento y la seguridad de este código se puede mejorar mucho, solo sirve a efectos ilustrativos.